# ArcGIS Online Routing service

Tags: arcgis-online, routing, network-analysis

I have a serious confusion understanding the link: http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/NetworkAnalysis
This is the default format to access the routing service, but this isn't complete, we have to tell further on which area we want to work such that
http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/NetworkAnalysis/SanDiego/NAServer/Route
The above link works only for San Diego but what if I want my network dataset and hence map to be uploaded as a link like this.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link you've referenced is a folder, and within that folder is a bunch of services. This is a "Sample Server", as such, it's used to demonstrate different workflows and patterns. Grouped inside this folder is pretty much everything you can do to support *Routing workflows*.

I'm not real sure exactly what you're asking, but I can try to explain what's inside this service folder.

You see 3 different services types:

- Map Service
- Geoprocessing Service
- Network Analyst Service

Each of these services *might* be using the same data (well, it's highly likely they are), but each service does something different.

The **map service** is obviously for looking at the data on a map. This will be a feature class of streets and other data layers that provide context for your user.

The **geoprocessing service** allows a user to actually generate a route or other network function. There's actually 6 different network tools inside the GP Service. The user of the application would send a request to the service where inside network analyst tools run, and provide a result. The application then draws the result on the map.

The **network analyst** service works similar to the geoprocessing service, but it's used differently. The application consuming the NA service needs to understand how to work with this particular service, specifically how to send a request and handle the response. It's a whole other question/topic why and when you'd use a GP Service vs NA Service.

With the services explained, if you want to do something similar, it all starts in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro with a streets featureclass. Publish your streets into a map service. Then create a Network Dataset and build/publish GP Services or publish the network into a NA Service. (This paragraph is an incredibly simplified explanation of the entire start to finish, somewhat complex workflow)

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the link and the services. Although I have developed a network dataset and published my map on ArcGIS online. But that is giving me this URL: https://services3.arcgis.com/6hlfw662PQfwuk07/arcgis/rest/services/IslamabadMap/FeatureServer , this link is not working for routing. I checked the ArcGIS REST API, but that is again pointing towards ArcGIS Server. I am not sure which step to follow next. Kindly guide me regarding this problem.

Comment: You cannot publish your own routing service to ArcGIS Online. You can only publish it to ArcGIS Server